# Ruby - Access instance variables of called class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, instance-variables

I have two classes Book::Utils, Table::Utils and I calling one class from the other which are not parent-child classes.

If I call class2 from class1 -> In class2, can we access already present class1 instance variables?

```
module Table
  attr_accessor :account_id
  class Utils
     def initialize(params)
       @account_id = params[:account_id]
     end

     def calculate
       book = Book.new
       final_account_id = book.get_account_id
       return final_account_id
     end
  end
end

module Book
  class Utils

    def get_account_id
      # Here I want to access Table's instance variables
      # Like @account_id + 20
    end
  end
end
```

I am calling `Table::Utils.new({account_id: 1}).calculate`

Expected result : `21`
Can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass instance of the class you need to call and then you can use accessors:

```
module Table
  attr_accessor :account_id
  class Utils
     def initialize(params)
       @account_id = params[:account_id]
     end

     def calculate
       book = Book.new
       final_account_id = book.get_account_id(self)
       return final_account_id
     end
  end
end

module Book
  class Utils

    def get_account_id(table)
      table.account_id + 20
    end
  end
end
```

or just pass the value that is needed

```
module Table
  attr_accessor :account_id
  class Utils
     def initialize(params)
       @account_id = params[:account_id]
     end

     def calculate
       book = Book.new
       final_account_id = book.get_account_id(account_id)
       return final_account_id
     end
  end
end

module Book
  class Utils

    def get_account_id(other_id)
      other_id + 20
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For 1 instance variable the solution is known. But its for many instance variables( params > 10)

Comment: What do you mean many instance variables? Just pass a class instance and then use accessors.

Comment: Ur first solution works i.e., book.get_account_id(self). Ideally I should pass more than 1 param in this. Ex: `get_account_id(@account_id, @user_id, @sync_id......etc)`. Passing self solves the problem. Thanks